# odd left proxy handle behavior in YUI 2.9 resize utility

Tags: javascript, html, yui

After I upgrade YUI from 2.8 to 2.9, the left handle proxy of resize utility is strange. See the **jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qianlifeng/atn67/4/**

`var resize = new YAHOO.util.Resize('resizeMe',{
    handles: ["l"],
    proxy:true
});`

When I drag the left handle, the proxy should expand from the left border. But now, it expand from the right border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there is no problem in YUI. The problem is that you must set the div position to be absolute, also fix the right. See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/atn67/5/

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
```